# How can I a load a Photosphere in my app?

Tags: android, photosphere

I made this question two days ago, and ianhanniballake replied me with the right solution. Now, I am trying to follow [this](http://my.fit.edu/~vkepuska/ece5570/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/samples/panorama/src/com/google/android/gms/samples/panorama/PanoramaSampleActivity.java) example.

Now, it's not loading the image.

I changed the line:

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.pano1);
```

for the line:

```
Uri.parse("http://s24.postimg.org/d81cxh2sl/pano1.jpg".toString());
```

What can it be?

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same problem did you solve it?

Comment: I did not try it anymore. I changed projects :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Android SDK you cannot use a http resource for that URI:

> the URI of the panorama to load info about. May be a file:, content:, or android_resource: scheme.

So you need to download the image first before you can process it. Check [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/android-load-images-from-web-and-caching.html) link for a tutorial on this.

Comment: Thank you, but it is not working yet. I'll try pasting my complete code.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll try following the tutorial provided.

Comment: No problem. I have edited my answer to correctly answer the problem you encountered.

Comment: @Trugath hi, I downloaded it and tried set the uri as the path of the file, and I got a null intent...